# Why is my Model.find().fetch() returning data from Mongodb on the server side but then returning [ ] on the client in Meteor?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor, frontend

I have added console logs in the schema file, and retrieved data from the database by running `meteor mongo` :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0d8af2b08fc89eadef0dd1"), "title" : "Hello world!" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0d8af9b08fc89eadef0dd2"), "title" : "Hello world!s" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0d9449b08fc89eadef0dd3"), "title" : "Hello world!s" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0f2d7eb08fc89eadef0dd4"), "title" : "Task1" }
```

and still, the same data is retrieved via the server-side through a console log I added on the subscription function:

**Schema.js**

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('tasks', function task() {
    console.log(Tasks.find({}).fetch(),' ttttttttttttttttttttttt');
    return Tasks.find({}).fetch();
  });
}
```

Then when I try to return the same data in another file, it actually fails to return the data and instead returns this in the console:
`[] "These are the results"`

**Get.js**

```
const getAllTasks=()=>{
        sub=Meteor.subscribe('tasks').ready();
            const tasks = Tasks.find({}).fetch();
            console.log(tasks, 'These are the results');
            return tasks
}
```

Here's my file structure

[image: general file structure]
[image: the detailed structure]

**Question**

Please help me figure out what I am potentially doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you exposing the pub to your client? Download meteor dev tools (I know this is on chrome but not sure of other browsers) and you can see which publications are reaching your client and what in your db the client has access to.